# Jersey/Spring/Grizzly Integration Tests Always Returns 500 - No Details

Tags: java, grizzly, jersey-test-framework, spring-jersey

I am trying to write some integration tests for an application that uses Jersey with some Spring DI. Tests always come back as a 500 with no real explaination. Grizzly appears to start ok and boots up my hibernate connections just fine. Here is the error trace along with all of relevant files sans the class under test. I think it may be an issue with Grizzly and the configuration but I cant find anything that seems to work including switching to a webappcontext.

```
javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Request failed.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1032)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:819)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
    at com.heapo.test.intergration.resources.UserResourceTest.test_getUser(UserResourceTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

**Test Class**

```
package com.sample.test.intergration.resources;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.TestProperties;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.sample.models.User;
import com.sample.rest.config.SampleApplication;
import com.sample.spring.config.SpringSecurityConfig;


public class UserResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Test
    public void test_getUser() {
        final User hello = target("user/1")
                                .request()
                                .header("Authorization", "BEARER xxx")
                            .get(User.class);
   }

   @Override
   protected Application configure() {
       enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
       enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);

        ResourceConfig rc = new ProgramProApplication();
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringSecurityConfig.class);
        rc.property("contextConfig", ctx);

        return rc;
    }
}
```

**Web.xml - works** - Application runs fine under Tomcat and I can access the entire API via postman.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Sample API</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Sample API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
             <param-value>com.sample.rest.config.SampleApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>        
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Sample API</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sample.spring.config.SpringSecurityConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>sample-api</groupId>
      <artifactId>sample-api</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>sample-api Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
        <jersey.scope>compile</jersey.scope>
        <spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.37</mysql.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Jersey core Servlet 2.x implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>${jersey.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey JSON Jackson (2.x) entity providers support module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>${jersey.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>${jersey.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey extension module providing support for Spring 3 integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>${jersey.scope}</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bean-validator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>            
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Framework-4.x -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Core 4.2.x -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>      
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySql-Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate c3p0 connection pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- TEST DEPENDENCIES -->
        <!-- Dependency for JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependency for Mockito -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>         
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>sample-api</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>    
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several days of trial and error with almost no documentation and piecing together from other examples there were out of date, this is what finally worked for me. Hopefully it will help somebody else.

**Test Class**

```
package com.sample.test.intergration.resources;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.TestProperties;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.sample.models.User;
import com.sample.rest.config.SampleApplication;
import com.sample.spring.config.SpringSecurityConfig;


public class UserResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Test
    public void test_getUser() {
        final User hello = target("user/1")
                            .request()
                            .header("Authorization", "BEARER xxx")
                            .get(User.class);
   }

    @Override
    protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
        return ServletDeploymentContext
                .forServlet(new ServletContainer(configureRC()))
                .addListener(ContextLoaderListener.class)
                .contextParam(ContextLoader.CONFIG_LOCATION_PARAM, SpringSecurityConfig.class.getPackage().getName())
                .contextParam(ContextLoader.CONTEXT_CLASS_PARAM, AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getName())
                .addFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.class, "springSecurityFilterChain")
                .build();       
    }   

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }       
}
```